AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'input'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Chydo\Dissertation\final\streamlit_app.py", line 36, in <module>
    feature_extractor = tf.keras.Model(inputs=cnn_model.input, outputs=cnn_model.layers[-2].output)
                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'input'

I am trying to create an web app using streamlit in vs code , im using the cnn and logistic regression model i created in jupyter
im getting this error please help
expecting the models to load then proceed to creating the front end to take user input and give a result based on combined accuracy of the two models

What the error is telling you is very simple. It cannot access cnn_model.input because cnn_model does not exist (or has value None). To give you any more help than that, you need to show us the code where cnn_model is created.

@steliosbl If cnn_model didn't exist there would be a NameError exception. Therefore we can deduce that it does exist and has a value of None
